# How to assign dynamic values to directory in inbound file adapter- Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have spring-batch-integration application where i poll a directory and with  file message i invoke the batch job. Now my polling directory have multiple sub-folders and in different conditions i have to poll different subfolder. directory structure as below.

```
inputData
    |_A
    |_B
    |_C
```

My Config to poll the directory

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter   id="pollFiles"
                                    prevent-duplicates="true"
                                    ignore-hidden="true"
                                    directory="classpath:/inputData"
                                    channel="files">
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I want directory value to be provided dynamically. eg. /inputData/#{subfolder}, Something like that . .

Have someone faced and resolved similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported - feel free to open a [new feature request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).